# Does standard (non-flexible) Google App Engine support Google Cloud Bigtable?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, bigtable, google-cloud-bigtable

Is there an official page, where this question is answered? In Nov 2016, I am trying to run some Java Bigtable code and it fails on both local dev server and on a real remote instance.

I have tried different versions of both libraries. Appengine either complains about using JMX or running threads. In both cases the usages of these technologies/APIs are deeply internal, being used by Bigtable client core for connection establishment etc.

Comment: Write me at lesv (at) g... about your use case and perhaps I can suggest a work around.

Comment: @LesVogel-GoogleDevRel: Thanks for the help! Our application uses both Bigtable and Objectify. As I understand, Ofy is not supported by GAE Flexible yet, so we have to split the application into different modules - a Bigtable module that will work on Flex env and the main module on the standard env that interacts with the Bigtable module via HTTP

Comment: Ah - Still not a bad idea to write me.  (Though I'm off next week, and traveling the following).

Comment: I've updated the answer by @LesVogel-GoogleDevRel below; you can now use Google App Engine standard with Cloud Bigtable!

Comment: Hello Misha! I just tried the example and Jetty fails with error: 

[INFO] GCLOUD: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.appengine.api.ThreadManager
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.IsolatedAppClassLoader.loadClass(IsolatedAppClassLoader.java:196)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)

Comment: The AppEngine version is 1.9.58, Java is OpenJDK 1.8.0_144, OS is Ubuntu 17.10, Maven 3.5.0. Thanks for the help!

Comment: The project code is not changed, tried with the standard maven command from the README.md: 

mvn -Dbigtable.projectID=AAA -Dbigtable.instanceID=BBB appengine:run

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can now use Cloud Bigtable from Google App Engine Standard, here is the [documentation with a code sample](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/samples-java-appengine-standard) and a [complete project](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine-java8/bigtable).

Answer (score 1):

You can use Cloud Bigtable in App Engine Standard, but only currently with Java (as far as I can see). As posted by another, [this repo](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine-java8/bigtable) and [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/samples-java-appengine-standard) contains a sample project of this being done.

Also, this is old but I found the answer to Aram's question in his comments. I can't comment directly so I am posting it here (not enough rep). The github repo is missing a dependency in the pom.xml file. Just add the following to the `<dependencies>` element to fix any errors:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
      <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.63</version>
    </dependency>
```